# How to show JSON column name using JPA?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

Within my entity class I have 3 Strings along with getters and setters.  I am using Jackson to display results.  I would like to see column and data like this...

```
[[id:"1", name:"Tim", address:"street"]]
```

However, I only get the data back without the column name as below...

```
[["1","Tom","street"]]
```

Is there a jackson annotation that would show the column name?  Does this have something to do with marshalling/unmarshalling?

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Personnel")
public class User implements Serializable {

private String id;
private String name;
private String address;

public User(String id, String name, String address) 
 {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
 }

@Id
@Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}....
//setters getters
```

**Impl**

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<User> getUsers() throws Exception{
List<User> userList= new ArrayList<User>();
String qry = "select u.id, u.name, u.address from User as u where u.name = 'Tim'" ;
List<String> jsonrows;
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(qry);  
userList.addAll(query.list());
return userList;
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/find", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public List<User> getUserName() {
 List<User> result= null;
    try {  
        { result = service.getUserList();
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {  
          e.printStackTrace();  
      } 
    return result;
}
```

So I tried to use GSON and then got back numbers for my column names with the code below.

Any ideas?

Comment: So your getUser() method returns a List, but a List of what? Use generics. We're not in 2004 anymore. And your select query selects things, but what? Show us the query.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your query doesn't actually return a `List<String>`. It returns a `List<Object[]>`, where each array contains 3 elements: the ID, the name and the address.

Since all you have is the values contained in the column, there is no way a JSON serializer can guess that the first element of the array is an ID, the second a name and the third an address.

You would have the JSON you want if, instead of returning a `List<Object[]>`, your query returned a `List<User>`. Then, Gson would have objects with named fields, and could transform those Java objects to JSON objects with the same fields.

So your query should simply be

```
 select u from User u where u.name = 'Tim'
```

And the method should return the `List<User>` returned by this query. By the way, this method should be named `getUsersNamedTim()`, and not `getUser()`, which implies that the method returns only one user.

Comment: Thanks JB.  I will make these fixes.

Comment: JB.  I made those changes:

Comment: Question updated with current code.  Once I started returning a User I received an accept/parameters 406 error.  So I then added Jackson to Pom file but still get numbers for column names.

Comment: What is unclear in "the query should be `select u from User u where u.name = 'Tim'`? You still select id, name and address, and the query thus still result arrays of object instead of User instances.